# Error expr: non-numeric argument while executing bash script

Tags: bash, shell

There is txt file-:

```
file1-
abhinav,Age_10,11,12,13,14,15
deepak,Age_10,11,12,13,14,15
file2-:
Dixit,15
Skoda,15
```

Shell script-:

```
old_count=`grep 'abhinav' |  awk  'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $2 }' | awk  'BEGIN { FS = "_" } ; { print $2 }'`
new_count=`grep 'dixit' | awk  'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $2 }'`
sum=`expr $old_count + $new_count`
```

But when this script is executed than error expr: non-numeric argument is coming . Though both variable $old_count $new_count are numeric.

Comment: `awk  'BEGIN { FS = "_" } ; { print $3 }'` wouldn't produce any output.  You wanted to print the second field, i.e., say `print $2` instead.

Comment: yes dev i want second value of T_10 i.e 10 to get into variable old_count. Apologies that was typo error but than also same error

Comment: You also have a `|` missing before `awk` in the same line.

Comment: After inserting | also result is same

Comment: Try some bit of debugging. Say `echo "#${old_count}#${new_count}#"` to see what it produces.

Answer (score 1):

Sidestepping whatever the problem actually is, it's simpler to write this as

```
old_count=$( awk -F, '/abhinav/ {split($2, a, "_"); print a[2]}' file1 )
new_count=$( awk -F, '/Dixit/ {print $2}' file2 )
sum=$(( old_count + new_count ))
```

One issue might have been that you were grepping for `dixit`, not `Dixit`, resulting in an empty value for `new_count`. I get a different error, but that could be based on the implementation of `expr`. Note that `expr` is no longer necessary for arithmetic in the shell; `$((...))` should be available in any POSIX-compliant shell.